# CSS how return calling element?

Tags: jquery, css

It looks like a very simple questions, but I could not find anywhere, so:

How do I return the caller element in Jquery?

```
$("div#myid").foo(); //I want to return exactly "div#myid"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('div#myid').selector;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you declared `foo` with:

```
$.fn.foo = function () {
};
```

If so, all you have to do is `return this;` inside that function.

```
$.fn.foo = function () {
    // do backflips
   return this;
};
```

Comment: this returns the target object, not the calling element tag in my example "div#myid".

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#selector').click(function(){
return this;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
 $.fn.foo = function () {

       return $(this).selector;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

you may also use this approach

```
$(("div#myid").click(function(){
$('b').text(this.tagName+ ' '+$(this).attr('id'))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

first update foo function

```
function foo(sender) {
   ......
   your code
   ......

   return sender;
 }
```

now you can call it from any where with any of the following calls

1. `$("div#myid").foo(this);`
2. `$("div#myid").foo($("div#myid"));`